# Why was this question closed and deleted when a similar one has 16 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

This question of mine was closed and deleted  (I didn't know it was deleted until someone pointed it out to me, since I can't view deleted questions)

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/do-we-have-any-portraits-of-the-ramban-nachmonides-and-how-authentic-are-they

Whereas this similar question has 16 upvotes

[Is this the Chofetz Chaim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/is-this-the-chofetz-chaim)

I think the RAMBAN is at least as much of a ganze macher as the Chofetz Chaim

So why was my question not acceptable whereas that one was?

Comment: @barlop Upvotes are irrelevant. Here are some upvoted closed questions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A10+closed%3A1+-%5Bpurim-torah-in-jest%5D 'Why wasn't it closed because it is similar' is on the other hand a good question.

Comment: @barlop In short, because the standards for "good questions" used to be natural; now they are draconian.

Answer (score 3):

It was closed because questions about Jewish people, which questions don't relate to Judaism per se, are off-topic. That's irrespective of what other questions may (perhaps inappropriately) remain open or have upvotes. And it was deleted automatically by a Stack Exchange script that deletes closed questions that aren't upvoted, and not by a human.